# Struts 2 Error Messages not working with simple theme

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am using struts 2 simple theme in my jsp in order to keep the css and layout as it is which I had used, if I use the default theme the whole layout of the jsp gets disturbed hence I have to use simple theme, but on the other hand I have to do validations , I have searched a lot about using the  tags but none of them is working, the solution which I used :

```
addActionError("Please Enter First Name !!!");
```

> then after reading some posts of stack overflow I changes it to

```
addFieldError("firstName","Please Enter First Name !!!" );


<s:textfield cssClass="w3-input w3-border"
placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" />
<s:fielderror> <s:param>firstName</s:param> </s:fielderror>
```

Please I request you to don't mark it as a duplicate since I had already tried all ways mentioned in the previous posts related to this, but then also it doen't solve my problem, Please help as I am stuck with this from 2 days!!!!!!!!

```
> I had also used the simple <s:fielderror> tag
```

> and also used
>   theme=css_xhtml but it again disturbs the whole layout of my jsp, so
>   is there any way besides the above solutions which I had tried??

Comment: Are you calling the default interceptor stack in your struts.xml? Can you post a copy/paste of your code there?

Comment: '<interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStackHibernateStrutsValidation">
     
    </interceptor-ref>
    

   </interceptor-stack>'

Comment: Post your action configuration.

Comment: And mention which version of S2 you're using. Please make sure you're adding the field error in the right method, too.